# Syntax error when trying to determine if select has a value selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to determine if a SELECT element has a value selected using the following code.

```
if (jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(7) select").is(':visible') && (jQuery('jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(5) select > [selected]').length > 0))      {
      // The following two lines are commands for a Prototype script, in place to simulate the change event
      setTimeout(function() {
          jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(6) select option").each(function() { this.selected = (this.text == "<?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName(); ?>"); });
          jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(6) select option").change();
          $('finder-4023--20454').simulate('click'); // This is the ID of the select element ( it is the same as div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(6) select )
          $('finder-4023--20454').simulate('change'); // This is the ID of the select element ( it is the same as div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(6) select )
          console.log('Changed!');
      }, 700);
      jQuery("#popover6").show();
  }
```

The problem I'm hitting is this error -- Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(5) select > [selected]

May you help with this syntax error?

Thanks!

Comment: this is what is wrong syntax: `jQuery('jQuery(...` Remove second jQuery from selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use select `option:selected` instead of wrong `select > [selected]` selector.

Your second part of the code is a bit messy, try this:

```
&& (jQuery('div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(5) select > option:selected').length > 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('jQuery("div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(5) select > [selected]')
```

Umm... not sure what you're trying to do there...?

Maybe this?

```
jQuery('div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(5) select > :selected')
```

Comment: i guess OP wants `:selected` but `[selected]` selector is still valid to retrieve default value of a select if specified in DOM

Answer (score 0):

The [selected selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) should be

```
[:selected]
```